# Use DATEADD(), but only if year is not 9999

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to perform a SQL query along the lines of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime < DATEADD(day, 1, EndDateTime)
```

The issue is that some of the EndDateTime's have the highest date possible, and when I try to run this query, I get an error: `Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.`

Any idea how I can use the EndDateTime itself instead of the EndDateTime + 1 day, if the date has a year of 9999?

Comment: I think you will need to use a different column type than `datetime`.  May I ask why you are working with the year `9999`?  Are you waiting for Enron stock to become valuable again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the logic in the other order:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE EndDateTime > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() );
```

This is also better because the query can take advantage of an index whose first key is `EndDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `case`

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
WHERE GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime < case 
      when year(EndDateTime) <> 9999 
      then DATEADD(day, 1, EndDateTime) 
      else EndDateTime 
end
```